# Ubuntu 18 with AMD ryzen3 2200g

Tags: kernel, amd-ryzen

I have a MSI B450 board with a ryzen3 2200g cpu and I want to switch to Ubuntu as win7 is not supported. I have read a number of posts with many claiming with Ubuntu 18 (as it ships with Kernel version 4.15) that it seems to me I will have the same issues with Ubuntu 18 lts as with win7 64bit. The partial solutions offered seem to say that later kernel versions (4.18 and later) may solve the problems. Is there a solution that a newbie with limited experience can apply to get this working?
Thank you for any help
Peterk